# Inspection of 'Regexp.union'

Tags: ruby, regex, code-inspection

`Regexp.union` returns the following inspection:

```
Regexp.union(/dogs/, /cats/i) #=> /(?-mix:dogs)|(?i-mx:cats)/
```

What does `?-mix:` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a representation of options on sub-regexes. The options to the left of the hyphen are *on*, and the options to the right of the hyphen are *off*. It's smart to explicitly set each option as on or off to ensure the right behavior if this regex ever became part of a larger one.

In your example, `(?-mix:dogs)` means that the `m`, `i`, and `x` options are all off whereas in `(?i-mx:cats)`, the `i` option is on and thus that subexpression is case-insensitive.

See the Ruby docs on [Regexp Options](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options):

> The end delimiter for a regexp can be followed by one or more single-letter options which control how the pattern can match.
>
> - `/pat/i` - Ignore case
> - `/pat/m` - Treat a newline as a character matched by .
> - `/pat/x` - Ignore whitespace and comments in the pattern
> - `/pat/o` - Perform #{} interpolation only once
>
> i, m, and x can also be applied on the subexpression level with the `(?on-off)` construct, which enables options *on*, and disables options *off* for the expression enclosed by the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

They are flag switches inside the regexp. `/cats/i` means "use flag `i` across the whole regexp". You can turn flags on and off inside a regexp, so the above is equivalent to `/(?i:cats)/`. There are two other flags that can be manipulated this way: `m` and `x`. Since by default all flags are disabled unless specified otherwise, it is equivalent to `/(?i-mx:cats)/` ("enable `i` and disable `m` and `x` inside the regular expression `cats`").

When you combine regular expressions, they explicitly disable the disabled flags so that they would not inherit them from an outer context. For example:

```
tiny = /tiny/             # case sensitive
tina = /#{tiny} tina/i    # case insensitive
# => /(?-mix:tiny) tina/i
```

This will match `"tiny tina"` or `"tiny Tina"`, but not `"Tiny Tina"`. If the embedded regexp for `tiny` did not explicitly turn off case sensitivity, and just yielded `/tiny tina/i`, everything would be case insensitive.